# android: use project's final static variable from inside the library, or some other tricks to exclude unused code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javac, android-library

I use android library (library project, not jar) to maintain 2 target projects (free and paid) with 1 code base. There is no code at all in target projects, all code is in library.

I need to add code blocks inside library:

```
if (main.liteVersion)
{
  //lite version code here
}
else
{
  //full version code here
}
```

As I know if variable in condition would be final static java compiler will exclude unused code (full version code if main.liteVersion is true). That's what I need. Because I don't want sobody decompile lite version and see code of the paid one. I know it's not a def, but I just don't include paid version code in free version binary.

But I can't add final static var in target project and then see it in library.

There are some ways to determine in which target project we are.
We could read current package name to determine which version is running.
If we add config class in target project we could use reflection in library to get a cfg value.
Also we can add resource in target project, but it will be added to com.tertium.lite.R, but in library we can read only com.tertium.library.R (of course using reflection we can read anything).
But such "dynamic" methods will not make compiler exclude unused code (in condition will be run-time calculated value).

We can rewrite config class inside library project while build (with ant or shell task) and then we'll have "natural" static setup, but I'd prefer not to touch library.

Just in case - I use eclipse helios, android versions - 1.6-4.2.

Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE: it's not actual anymore, since I've refused from using project as a library and have developed seamless ant-based resource-compile-and-build workflow which supports all needed configurations.
Moreover, as far as I know my original question has no valid answer.

Comment: I'd recommend writing different implementation of classes and interfaces with same name but in different packages. Let pro version classes extend free version ones and add more functionality.

Comment: And for project variables take a look at the manifest metadata :
http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/10/08/using-meta-data-in-an-androidmanifest/

Comment: @User117 it's very inconvenient, especially when it is a game and you should sacrifice architecture for performance. Also it is much more code. By the way I need not 2 but 5 different configurations which differ by small bits of code and resouces.

Comment: @meh, thanks for the tip, didn't know this. But technically it's just like reading current package name - it's dynamic and runtime. I still think about pre-build code change, while I don't like it. I miss C++ so much, its predefined macros in project settings and preprocessor :)

Comment: @Tertium yea i'm having problems with that too, there is also another thing I have encountered its called 'proguard' it is only used when you are creating a signed apk. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you make it step of you build system (ant, maven, make, etc). I hope, there are only few such pieces of source, so you can add file replacement manual as build step.

Don't make this compiler work: it's hard to control in long-terms. Compiler options/version will change and behaviour can change as well.

Comment: Yes, I can add as a build step, but the question is - can I somehow make javac exclude some code on the build stage of project that uses this library? I mean they are compiled in the same flow, so it should be possible. But I don't want to replace code of library in pre-build step because when I open another target project (free or paid) I need to manually rebuild it: when I change library code target project wouldn't rebuild automatically. And I can somehow forget to  rebuild and target become free instead of paid and vice versa. Hope you understand...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unused code using ProGuard (on the application projects, not on the library project). If there is no code at all in the application projects, you may need to resort to different `proguard-project.txt` files in each application project and make sure you don't keep any paid entry point in the free version

ProGuard rules are a bit tricky, you can see wich classes and methods have been kept in the `proguard/mapping.txt` file

Comment: Google recommends not to use code shrinking by Proguard. I have also negative experience of using it (unpredictable problems on some devices, have gone after I turned on optimizations, as google recommends). Moreover, Dalvik performs some code optimizations with unused code itself. BUT: even Proguard can't remove code which depends on some runtime evaluating value - program can change it in runtime and what then if code was removed? That's why this will not help.

Comment: Google **recommend** using Proguard, see https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html :  **Having ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended.**. By the way it is almost necessary if you don't want the code to be easily reverse enginerred

Comment: open \Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt and read this: "Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some of these optimizations on its own).". Even in optimized conf: "Adding optimization introduces certain risks, since for example not all optimizations performed by ProGuard works on all versions of Dalvik.  The following flags turn off various optimizations known to have issues, but the list may not be complete or up to date... Make sure you test thoroughly if you go this route. "

Comment: ok, the optimization step of ProGuard is disabled, but the shrink and obfuscation steps are enabled, useful (and recommended). I never touch the global config file, but a lot of unused class and methods are removed when I compile in release mode

Comment: javac will remove unused code itself - if it'd know it is unused. But it's important to understand that in compile-time it's impossible to determine which code is unused if you have variable (instead of final static) in condition, which can be changed in runtime, even implicitly with some pre-encrypted dynamic bash code or reflection. That's why generally shrinking in this situation is an "unsolvable problem". And yes, I do use Proguard, as most android devs do.

Comment: javac don't remove code unless it is absolutely sure that it can't be used, e.g. it never removes public classes and methods. ProGuard is much more aggressive and removes anything that seems to be actually unused. Obviously as it is a static analysis, it may miss some access (e.g. via reflexion). That's why you need to tell it what to keep.

Comment: Thanks for note. But I meant pieces of code inside methods. Ok, I think this needs detailed investigation.